# node ./bin/www error elifecycle - what's wrong with this error log?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.6
3 info using node@v14.6.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~prestart: shopping-cart@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: shopping-cart@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/rbalabarcon/shopping-cart/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
9 verbose lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/rbalabarcon/shopping-cart
10 silly lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node ./bin/www' ]
11 silly lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle shopping-cart@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: shopping-cart@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid shopping-cart@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/rbalabarcon/shopping-cart
16 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v14.6.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error shopping-cart@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the shopping-cart@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Package.json code below:

```
{
  "name": "shopping-cart",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.1.0",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.6.0",
    "hbs": "^4.1.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.9",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact command you are using and your `package.json` file?

Comment: {
  "name": "shopping-cart",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.1.0",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.6.0",
    "hbs": "^4.1.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.9",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  },

Comment: Thanks, but update your question and format it there!

Comment: thanks but what do you mean by format it there? can you please elaborate?

Comment: I meant, edit your question, paste the content of `package.json` there and use formatting tools to make it easier to read (like you did with your current code snippet).

Comment: Thanks for sharing it, check out [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to see how to format code in your questions/answers! Now, can you maybe tell why are you using `node ./bin/www` command to start your script (I assume you are trying to run `npm start` which is defined to run `node ./bin/www` in your `package.json`)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Appreciated it. it was there by default and i delete the file (bin/www) once and restored it back when I got i could not access the localhost. I assumed it was the issue so I got it back and this is giving me another issue. Thanks!